# Now that I've asked a question - how do I find it again, if there aren't any replies yet?

Tags: support, profile-page

I don't see a link to click for "Subscribed" questions.  I will be leaving this tab open in the browser and refresh it in order to be able to find the question again, and see if there are any answers.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion - you massively edited this question?  That's just unnecessary to do to me to make me feel bad over nothing.  It was understand able enough for 1) you to figure it out and 2) someone to reply with what turned out to be an answer before you edited.  I'm bothered by this!!!  I wish you'd taken a moment to answer it too.

Comment: I had used replies yet because it's not an answer until it works.  Though I will agree that answer is probably easier for a passerby to figure out quickly.

Comment: Please don't be bothered by someone who edits your post (see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)). He's just trying to be helpful by improving the question. That's just the way things work over here ;-)

Comment: Thanks Lucas -- he could edit something that wasn't understandable.  For me, it, it makes me feel badly to have my words changed by someone else for what doesn't seem like an obvious reason...oh well.

Comment: Really  curious why -3 on this question.  It offended people that I asked this?? Really?  They didn't post any complaints.  This part of stack overflow with the option of people endless niggling at you, and even attacking under guise of the rules - is one aspect of SO that I don't care for.  It makes me nerveous every time I come near or post -- "what trivial will I encounter today?"  Not cool stuff, in my view.

Comment: It was downvoted because, well, the answer seems obvious for most people here ;-) Also, voting on meta doesn't count towards rep. Note that if you disagree with an edit, you can rollback it anytime, but people edit other people's posts all the time over here, so unless you feel strongly about an edit in particular, just let it go.

Comment: Lucas - thanks for the explanation.  I find it odd, but it helps to know the over context of how this works.

Comment: As for the answer being too obvious -- in my book that's an extremely rude reason to down vote someone.  I come from tradition of asking questions and it's bad form to make someone feel bad for asking something.  Obviously it the answer wasn't obvious.  I couldn't find the answer --- and I did later see someone else post a very similar question.  Oh well.  If people want to spend their time downvoting a question for being obvious to them, that's what's so in their life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the (non deleted) questions that you asked are listed on your profile.

Your meta profile is at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4060469/curls?tab=questions.

And your main site profile is at https://stackoverflow.com/users/4060469/curls?tab=questions

That link can be found by clicking on your avatar and reputation at the top, centre of any page whilst logged in (or your username on any previous post), selecting "activity" then "Questions".

*Recent* deleted questions, if any, can also be seen (by you only) by clicking the corresponding link on that page.

NB: To see activity across Stack Exchanges per your comment you can look at your network profile. Linked from any individual site profile.

In your case the link is to https://stackexchange.com/users/5057815/curls?tab=activity

Comment: Thanks.   My name's not at the top of the page.   I'm not sure why you are focused on deleted questions.  I'm not complaining that my questions  disappeared.  My ability to navigate the site is missing.  I can see a list of the forum questions and nothing at the top of the page that would lead anywhere?

Comment: @curls if you are logged in you should see your avatar and reputation at the top, centre. Click on that and it takes you to your profile. Reason for mentioning deleted questions was just to be comprehensive about what is shown there.

Comment: I see.  It's the picture, not my name that's at the top.  And it only goes to questions for the particular stack I'm on.  I guess I have to dig on the stuff on the top left if I want to find the other stacks I was in.  But now I see how to get to my name... and from there to questions... and from there to replies.